# Elastic Job in Azure is failing when scheduled, but runs fine if I trigger it manually

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using Elastic Job Agents on Azure in order to run a couple of store procedures during the weekend for DB maintenance for SQL Azure DBs.

But even though I’m able to successfully run the jobs using sp_start_job, when the jobs are scheduled I’m getting this error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Msg 297, The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

Full stack trace:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.Jobs.Core.UserException: Command failed: Msg 297, The user does not have permission to perform this action.
    
Date and time: 2023-10-22 04:45:55
     ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Msg 297, The user does not have permission to perform this action.
    
Date and time: 2023-10-22 04:45:55
    
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 2363
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 1835
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 0
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlDataReader.cs:line 1349
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlDataReader.cs:line 281
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlCommand.cs:line 5787
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlCommand.cs:line 5665
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteReader(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlCommand.cs:line 2927
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteReaderInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlCommand.cs:line 2602
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteReaderAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlCommand.cs:line 2567
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.Jobs.Core.ScriptExecutionTaskExecutor.<ExecuteBatchAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.Jobs.Core.ScriptExecutionTaskExecutor.<ExecuteBatchAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.Jobs.Core.ScriptExecutionTaskExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.Jobs.Core.UserException: Command failed: Msg 297, The user does not have permission to perform this action.
    
Date and time: 2023-10-22 04:45:55
     ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Msg 297, The user does not have permission to perform this action.
    
Date and time: 2023-10-22 04:45:55
    
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 2363
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 1835
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 0
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlDataReader.cs:line 1349
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlDataReader.cs:line 281
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlCommand.cs:line 5787
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlCommand.cs:line 5665
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteReader(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlCommand.cs:line 2927
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteReaderInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlCommand.cs:line 2602
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteReaderAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlCommand.cs:line 2567
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.Jobs.Core.ScriptExecutionTaskExecutor.<ExecuteBatchAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.Jobs.Core.ScriptExecutionTaskExecutor.<ExecuteBatchAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.Jobs.Core.ScriptExecutionTaskExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()<---
```

I double checked the permissions for the user running the job and everything seems to be fine, so I need help in order to troubleshoot this issue.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks!

-Gustavo

Comment: I think the Elasitc jobs still in preview, also have you created the credentials required?

Comment: yes, it's still on preview, but we've been using them for some time already. Credentials are in place, we're able to run the job successfully using sp_start_job, but when it runs scheduled, then if fails.

Comment: May be it’s a bug, in scheduled job, credentials must be stored in job somewhere.